# Execute commands on remote host from a c program

Tags: c, linux, ssh

I am trying to automate a process of logging on the firewall server, exporting some logs , scp the logs to local host then delete it from the remote server (firewall server)

I also enabled host based authentication so that both machines would communicate without entering the password of either machine during ssh-ing and transfering.

I started by using system calls thinking it would work but it does not seem that it works as anticipated. What I did was something like this

```
system(ssh user@firewallserver)
system(cd /directory)
system(fwm logexport)
system(scp log user@localhost:/home)
system(rm log)
```

people who tried this in the past will know that this does not work, but I do not know a solution or maybe a different way of accomplishing the task.

Thanks!

Comment: Are looking for the hardest possible way to do this?  Why C?  System spawns a shell so, for instance, whatever you CD to means nothing to the C program.

Comment: so whats the alternative to system()?

Comment: I'm no sysadmin but this seems like something `expect` would be perfect for.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: exec() ?? not sure how to do it though, it'll be greate if you give me a quick example

Comment: Have you tried 'rsh' (remote shell)?

Comment: If you find yourself doing a lengthy sequence of `system()` calls, it's likely you want to actually write a shell script, not a C program (or C++ or ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this could be done effectively, in a bash script do the following

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@host 'bash -l' < ~/dowork.sh
```

the "dowork.sh" script is what you want to execute on the remote machine, you have to break those up to two scripts and redirect the dowork.sh to the ssh when executing the command

to verify that you got a shell into the correct machine do this in "dowork.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH
```

and this will give you the path variable from the remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

Each `system` command opens new process so that your ssh session is gone in second call. Try to do it in one command if you really want to use `system`:

`ssh server <some commands on server side>`

`scp <path on server> <local path>`

Edit:
Try

`ssh server 'cd /directory && touch test123'`

on the command line. This should create the file `test123` on the remote server in directory `/directory`. Then put this command in your `system(...)` call. In this way you can execute commands on the remote host. For every new `system` call you must do again `ssh server <commands>` ...

If you don't need it in a C program you can put these commands directly in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh server 'cd /directory && touch test123'
scp server:/directory/test123 /home/me/log123
```

Comment: I tried that to, it will end up running the rest of the commands on localhost rather on remote host. I am not insisting on using system I could use an alternative if you have a different idea

Comment: bash script or expect is what I am probably going to use, apparently it is a hassle to do it through a C program.

Comment: The problem with solution is that it goes and ssh into the remote machine just fine and then I get a prompt on the remote machine but the rest of the script wont execute remotely, it will wait for me to type exit and quit the ssh then it will execute the rest of the commands locally. I tried it exacltly like you said without making it too complicated I just created a testfile.txt on the remote and tried to cd to its location and remove it.

Comment: this works just fine it is not what I was trying to do ssh user@firewallserver 'bash -s' < local_script.sh

Answer (score 0):

Bash is definitely the way to go! You can just stick these commands straight into a script and it should work if you've set up your authentication properly.

The script would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@firewallserver
cd /directory
fwm logexport
scp log user@localhost:/home #Possible mistake
rm log
```

Now I've looked through your code there could be a misunderstanding. I take it that you're supposed to move `log` back to the original machine that you `ssh`-ed into `firewallserver` from.

If that's the case you can't use `localhost` in your `scp` call, because that's the `firewallserver`. You need to `scp log user@<your local IP>` to get the log back to the machine you logged in from.

Perhaps I've misunderstood, if that's the case then the script I posted above should work. However, if I'm correct then just swap the `scp` line and that should work.

Comment: The problem with solution is that it goes and ssh into the remote machine just fine and then I get a prompt on the remote machine but the rest of the script wont execute remotely, it will wait for me to type exit and quit the ssh then it will execute the rest of the commands locally. I tried it exacltly like you said without making it too complicated I just created a testfile.txt on the remote and tried to cd to its location and remove it.

Comment: ssh user@firewallserver 'bash -s' < local_script.sh